# vagrant hangs trying to bring up virtual machine with aws [ ec2 (amazon web services) ] as provisioner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant

I can't figure out why things are freezing up when I issue the following command:

```
$ vagrant up --debug --provider=aws
```

The output I get up to the point my process freezes  is show below in "Error Output"

My `Vagrantfile` is given below. There is not much more than this. Maybe there is something obvious 
visible in the error output?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true


  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "yabadabadoo"
    aws.secret_access_key = "yabadabadoo"
    aws.keypair_name = "zoozooLa-key01"
    aws.ami = 'ami-7747d01e'        # ubuntu 12.04
    override.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
    override.ssh.private_key_path = './zoozooLa-key01.pem'

  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest:4444, host:4444
end
```

**Error Output**

```
 INFO host: Detected: windows!
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x3f349f8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::HandleBox:0x47bb738>
 INFO handle_box: Machine already has box. HandleBox will not run.
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x481d898>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x481d880>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x487b618>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x48fbda8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x4903140>
 INFO machine: Calling action: read_state on provider AWS (new)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x49d2db8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x49f3398>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x49f32f0>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x4a56860>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x4a56860>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x49f32f0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x49f3398>
 INFO machine: New machine ID: nil
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x4903140>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x56df360>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x57f9270@C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Provision:0x56df318>
 INFO provision: Checking provisioner sentinel file...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x5709e28>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0/powershell.EXE", "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 2
```

Comment: which aws plugin do you install in vagrant? Is this one `https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws`, I did it before, no problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug with synced folders on Windows. Can you confirm that your host OS is Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a windows issue !     I tried on an ubuntu host and it works just fine.

thank you Seth and BMW.
 -chris

Comment: sorry..  don't use that OS anymore